# Spatial join in Django

Tags: python, django, postgis

I am trying to do a spatial join ([as explaind here](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/joins.html)) using PostGIS within Django.

The [Django spatial lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/) do not help. My best clue is to use custom SQL but I would really prefer to keep using a `QuerySet` query.

In plain english my query would be: Select all estates which *contains* at least one building with type "heavy"

Here are my two models:

```py
class Building(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, db_index=True)
    footprint = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    perimeter = models.PolygonField(null=True, spatial_index=True)

class Estate(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    area = models.IntegerField(null=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    perimeter = models.PolygonField(null=True, validators=[estate_val.perimeter], spatial_index=True)
```

Is there any way to do something like:

```py
estates = Estate.objects.filter(CUSTOM_JOIN_FILTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't [Q Object](https://riptutorial.com/django/example/4565/advanced-queries-with-q-objects) what are u looking for ?

You can do pretty complex queries using Q Object.